# How can I patch holes in the roof left by satellite dish removal?

Tags: roof

My house came with 2 satellite dishes mounted to the roof around the same place.  I've never used them.  Recently, wind managed to push them down so that one came down completely and the other was still hanging by 2 of its 4 lag bolts.

I've removed them complete and left the lag bolts in the holes.  Is there a best way to close the holes before replacing the asphalt shingles?  Or should I just put caulk around the lag bolts and leave it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Leaving the lag bolts in is fine, but the bolts are likely made out of galvanized steel, meaning they will rust and corrode eventually when exposed to constant rain and water.  It is best to liberally apply roof cement patch to the lag bolts to ensure that no water will corrode or leak through where the bolts are.

You can get roof cement patch in a tube form like so that easily fits into a standard caulking gun.

[image]

It will eventually wear away so I would check on the patches every 3 or 4 years to make sure they are still there.

Comment: +1 for the roof cement. But if the shingles are going on top of the lag bolts, I'd remove them and fill the holes with some extra roof cement. You don't want anything sticking up that would wear out the shingle from below.

Comment: Something that requires maintenance every 3-4 years doesn't sound very good for the next owner.

Answer (score 0):

Better yet, lift the top layer of shingle where the holes are and apply flashing secured with roof cement.